# Permenant Route Addition

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, routing, ip

I'm trying to add a route permanently to my VPS, at the moment I have to run the command manually every time I find out the server has rebooted. I read somewhere I had to add something to /etc/network/interfaces but it didn't match my setup - I have multiple interfaces and the method didn't seem to match what I saw in the file.

My command I run (as root) is:

```
ip route add 10.33.252.0/24 via 10.33.252.75
```

My /etc/network/interfaces file looks like:

```
# This configuration file is auto-generated.
#
# WARNING: Do not edit this file, your changes will be lost.
# Please create/edit /etc/network/interfaces.head and
# /etc/network/interfaces.tail instead, their contents will be
# inserted at the beginning and at the end of this file, respectively.
#
# NOTE: it is NOT guaranteed that the contents of /etc/network/interfaces.tail
# will be at the very end of this file.
#

# Auto generated lo interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Auto generated venet0 interface
auto venet0
iface venet0 inet manual
        up ifconfig venet0 up
        up ifconfig venet0 127.0.0.2
        up route add default dev venet0
        down route del default dev venet0
        down ifconfig venet0 down


iface venet0 inet6 manual
        up route -A inet6 add default dev venet0
        down route -A inet6 del default dev venet0

auto venet0:0
iface venet0:0 inet static
        address 198.91.90.242
        netmask 255.255.255.255

auto venet0:1
iface venet0:1 inet static
        address 69.175.32.40
        netmask 255.255.255.255

auto venet0:2
iface venet0:2 inet static
        address 69.175.32.41
        netmask 255.255.255.255

auto venet0:3
iface venet0:3 inet static
        address 69.175.32.42
        netmask 255.255.255.255

auto venet0:4
iface venet0:4 inet static
        address 69.175.32.43
        netmask 255.255.255.255

auto venet0:5
iface venet0:5 inet static
        address 69.175.32.138
        netmask 255.255.255.255

auto venet0:6
iface venet0:6 inet static
        address 173.236.6.220
        netmask 255.255.255.255

auto venet0:7
iface venet0:7 inet static
        address 198.91.90.243
        netmask 255.255.255.255

auto venet0:8
iface venet0:8 inet static
        address 10.33.252.75
        netmask 255.255.255.255
```

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: You can put like this: `up route add -net 10.33.252.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.33.252.75` under `/etc/network/interfaces` and should work.

Comment: @Achu - Which venet do I put it under? venet0:8 or venet0?

Comment: I think you don't need to specify the interface. If you want you can add `dev venet0:8` at the last.

Comment: How was it? didn't work for you?